# "Project Management" in Latin

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation, modern-life, word-choice

I was looking for a translation for "project management" and its adjacents (project manager etc.). There's surprisingly few direct translations for "project", but I've managed to dig up a few words I like.

"Opus" is probably the most obvious, it's a common word and encompasses most of what a project entails. It is, however, a little too general for my taste, especially considering that project management in a narrower sense is specifically about singular, unique tasks. This also more or less disqualifies "negotium" or "pensum" for which this seems even more true.

As opposed to that I have found "commentum", which maybe goes a little too far in the other direction, focusing more on the creative aspect of having come up with a plan as it derives from "comminisci" "to invent". I fear that using "commentum" might imply more the management of ideas and plans themselves than their implementation, but I have a soft spot for the word, because it can also mean "fabrication, falsehood", and as a project manager myself this seems very fitting.

An that's pretty much all the good ones I was able to find. Lewis and Short also quote "cogitatio", but using it in the meaning of "plan, design, resolution" feels rather far from its primary meanings and could invite misunderstanding. "Commentum" seems superior to "cogitatio" for this usage if I wanted to go in the direction of "plan" rather than "task" or "work". So my decision would be between "opus", "commentum" and any suggestions you fine people might have for me.

"Management" on the other hand has a good deal of possible translations, with "administratio", "(pro)curatio", "gubernatio" and others. For "manager", "moderator" or "vilicus" also seem fine, but "moderamen" and "vilicatio" stray a bit far from my intention, with "moderamen" apparently focusing more on the means of managing than the task itself and "vilicatio" being fairly specifically about managing a "villa".

Personally, I'm partial to "curatio" and "curator", but someone with a better grasp of the finer differences might disagree for reasons I am eager to learn.

Grammatically this seems simple enough and we'd probably arrive at something like "curatio commentorum" or "curatio operum" if I'm not mistaken. So does anyone know alternative word choices or can advise about mine?

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with the choice of  "curator" to translate "manager."  Something as general as "project" could be best translated by "res" ("rei"), if at all.  You might even leave "project" untranslated, since "curator" implies there is business or task *curandum*.

Answer (score 0):

I think that project may me translated as *operatio*, meaing operation wich is a kind of mean the same as project. Otherwise I think that Kevin got it right.